# How do i install zukitwo?

Tags: themes

I found the theme here:

http://lassekongo83.deviantart.com/art/Zukitwo-203936861

I went in here:

https://github.com/lassekongo83/zuki-themes

Downloaded everything and I also did:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

But, what do I do now? I have the folder with everything that I downloaded from the github source but I don't know what to do with it.

I'm new to Ubuntu, I'm trying to learn as fast as I can.

I have Ubuntu gnome 14.10.

Comment: Important note: This theme is designed for Gnome 3.14. May or may not work with other versions of Gnome-shell and GTK. Says the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the .zip file and move the folder Zukitwo to `/usr/share/themes`.
Step by step:

1. click the .zip file in the browser
2. select the folder Zukitwo
3. click "Unpack" and select e.g. your Desktop folder
4. Open a terminal: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
5. Enter the following command: `sudo mv ~/Desktop/Zukitwo /usr/share/themes/`
6. Enter your password at the prompt.

Where to move the theme folders is explained in more detail in the INSTALL file, which is also in the zip.

The INSTALL instructions then go on about how to actually select Zukitwo as the current theme, using terminal commands. However, you can easily switch themes by using System Settings/Appearance, or by installing `unity-tweak-tool` which you can find [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-tweak-tool/).

Comment: thanks for the answer! i was looking for installation instructions for a while before asking this question but didnt find them, where are they? also, im unable to copy anything into the theme folder, it seems to be locked and i have no permissions to make any changes on it, what can i do?

Comment: Found it downloading another folder. Nevermind, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is for Ubuntu 14.10/14.04

To install Zukitwo Dark Cinnamon theme:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zukitwo-dark-cinnamon
```

To install Zukitwo Dark Gnome Shell theme:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zukitwo-dark-shell
```

To install Zukitwo theme:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zukitwo
```

To install Zukiwi theme:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zukiwi
```

**Gnome Shell version**
[image]
**Gnome Shell version**
[image]
**Cinnamon version**
[image]
**Unity version**
[image]

Source: [Noobslab](http://www.noobslab.com/)

To apply a theme you can use either Ubuntu-Tweak tool or Unity Tweak tool or Gnome Tweak tool. To install Ubuntu Tweak tool:

[image]

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

To install Unity Tweak tool:

[image]

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

To install Gnome Tweak tool:

[image]

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Just go to applications and type in Dash search any of them and launch it.

**P.S.**

To change shell themes in Gnome don't forget to install `gnome-shell-extensions` and enable user themes.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
```

Comment: You might want to explain how to activate the theme once installed.

Comment: yes I'm working on that